# How to nicely intersect two sets build from two maps?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, set, java-stream

Our objects have "properties"; and their current state is represented as `Map<String, Object>` where the key resembles the name of the property. The values can have different types, my current task is only dealing with *Boolean* properties though.

Beyond the current status, also "updates" to objects are organized via such maps.

Now I have to prevent that a property that is currently `true` gets disabled (turned to `false`).

Using streams, this here works:

```
Set<String> currentlyEnabled = currentObjectPropertiesMap.
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(e.getValue()))
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<String> goingDisabled = updatedObjectPropertiesMap
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> Boolean.FALSE.equals(e.getValue()))
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

currentlyEnabled.retainAll(goingDisabled);

if (currentlyEnabled.isEmpty()) {
    return;
} else {
  throw new SomeExceptionThatKnowsAllBadProperties(currentlyEnabled);
}
```

The above code first fetches a set of all properties that are `true`, then it separately collects all properties that will turn `false`. And if the intersection of these two sets is empty, I am fine, otherwise error.

The above works, but I find it clumsy, and I dislike the fact that the `currentlyEnabled` set is misused to compute the intersection.

Any suggestion how this can be done in a more idiomatic, but readable "stream-ish" way?

Comment: Why not iterate over `currentObjectPropertiesMap.entrySet()`, `continue` on entries where the values are `false`, otherwise, check if `updatedObjectPropertiesMap.hasKey()` and if it's true, then throw exception if the value for that key is `false`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just select all key-value-pairs whose value is `true`, and then via the key, check if the value from the "update"-map is `false`.

```
Set<String> matches = currentObjectPropertiesMap
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(e.getValue()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .filter(k -> Boolean.FALSE.equals(
        updatedObjectPropertiesMap.get(k)
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

if(!matches.isEmpty()) throw ...
```

Comment: Can combine the two `filter`s into one and then `map`. Though not much of a difference `.filter(e -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(e.getValue()) &&
                        Boolean.FALSE.equals(updatedObjectPropertiesMap.get(e.getKey())))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)`

Comment: @Naman I agree, but IMO, stream statements should be as simple as possible. My rule of thumb is one condition/statement per `filter`/`map`-operation (if possible), but as said this is just an opinion

Comment: For efficiency, you may check, which map is smaller and iterate over the smaller one, i.e. if `updatedObjectPropertiesMap` is smaller, use `Set<String> matches = updatedObjectPropertiesMap .entrySet() .stream() .filter(e -> Boolean.FALSE.equals(e.getValue())) .map(Map.Entry::getKey) .filter(k -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(currentObjectPropertiesMap.get(k))) .collect(Collectors.toSet());` instead; the result will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

One solution that ***does not*** include explicit set intersection could be:

```
Set<String> violatingProperties = new HashSet<String>();
for (Entry<String, Object> entry : currentObjectPropertiesMap.entrySet()) {
    if (! (Boolean) entry.getValue()) {
        continue;
    }
    if (! updatedObjectPropertiesMap.hasKey(entry.getKey())) {
        continue;
    }
    if (! (Boolean) updatedObjectPropertiesMap.get(entry.getKey())) {
        violatingProperties.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
if (violatingProperties.size() > 0) {
    throw ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I A) prefer a stream solution and B) I need to "collect" all property names that violate my condition.

Comment: Updated the code such that the violating property names will be saved

Answer (score 0):

Try `anyMatch`

```
boolean anyMatch = currentXXXMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(e -> e.getValue() && !updatedXXXMap.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), true));
```